# About an $L^\infty$ equality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $\Bbb R$ and $c $ be a positive real number. Let $x \in [0,K]$ for some $K >0$. Then does there exist a constant $C >0$ such that $$  \| f(cx) \|_{L^\infty([0,K])} = C \| f(x) \|_{L^\infty([0,K])}  ?$$

Comment: Should $C$ be the same constant for all $c$? Do you want to show the equality for all $c$?

Comment: @macydanim No, $c$ and $C$ are different. I want to find such $C$ or if exists, then I want to know the dependence .

Comment: Your assumption that $x\in[0,K]$ is meaningless in the context of the question.

Comment: I know that $c$ and $C$ are meant to be different, but do you want $C$ to depend on $c$ i.e. $C=C(c)$ ?

Comment: @Eckhard I think $x \in [0,K]$ guarantees that $f$ is bounded on $\Bbb R$ because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: But if you have $x\in [0,K]$ why do you chose the $||\cdot||_{L^{\infty} R}$ norm and not only on $[0,K]$

Comment: @macydanim Yes, you are right. That should be replaced by $[0,K]$ I will change.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,K]$, but that is not relevant if one considers the $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ norm. That being said, the notation $\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})}$ is not well-defined, even less if you restrict $x$ to an interval $[0,K]$.

Comment: @Eckhard In fact $L^\infty$ is just a maximum in this case.

Comment: So does $C$ depend on $c$ ? Because if so, the formulation would be trivial. Or do you want the same $C$ for all $c$ ?

Comment: @macydanim I hope $C$ to be depend on $c$.

Comment: Well then chose C = $||f(cx)||_{L^{\infty}} / ||f(x)||_{L^\infty} $for all $f \not \equiv 0$.

Comment: @macydanim Thank you very much. I was a little confused.

Comment: So that was the answer you wanted ? Because that won't help that much in any application ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c=1$, then obviously, we can take $C=1$. Otherwise, there can be no such $C$.

If $c\lt1$, let
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }x\le cK\\
\frac{x-cK}{(1-c)K}&\text{if }cK\lt x\lt K\\
1&\text{if }x\ge K
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty([0,K])}=1$, yet $\|f(cx)\|_{L^\infty([0,K])}=\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty([0,cK])}=0$

If $c\gt1$, let
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }x\le K\\
\frac{x-K}{(c-1)K}&\text{if }K\lt x\lt cK\\
1&\text{if }x\ge cK
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty([0,K])}=0$, yet $\|f(cx)\|_{L^\infty([0,K])}=\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty([0,cK])}=1$

Comment: You should modify your construction of $f$ to satisfy the continuity condition.

Comment: @richard: thanks. I was too busy thinking about $L^\infty$.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @richard @ robjohn Thank you, but how it becomes if $f$ is differentiable and the $L^\infty$ norm of $f(x)$ and $f(cx)$ nonzero?

Comment: @Kamon: you can have $f\in C^\infty$ and have $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\ge1$ as long as you don't have an upper limit on $\|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Comment: @Kamon: e.g.
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
m&\text{if }x\le x_m\\
m+\frac{M-m}{1+\exp\left(\frac1{x-x_m}+\frac1{x-x_M}\right)}&\text{if }x_m\lt x\lt x_M\\
M&\text{if }x\ge x_M
\end{array}\right.
$$